# How to Hide Firefox Camera Icon Overlay in Windows

Tags: firefox, getusermedia, kiosk-mode

I'm working on a kiosk project that uses Firefox and mozGetUserMedia to access an attached camera.

The problem is, even using kiosk addons (like mKiosk) this icon appears at the top of the screen whenever the camera is accessed using mozGetUserMedia:

[image]

Here you can see it at the top of the screen.
[image]

I have tried searching through the options on the

```
about:config
```

page, but I can't find any setting that disables this. It only shows up on Windows, and not OS X.

How can I disable this icon?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the `about:config` settings, set `privacy.webrtc.legacyGlobalIndicator` to false.

Comment: I think, in 2021, this should be the accepted answer. It's simple and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the only way to do this is to write a custom add-on it seems. I just encountered a similar issue where I had to remove the overlay for an embedded application.

You can download the add-on [here](https://github.com/yannleretaille/firefox-addon-webrtcindicatorremover).

Note: This add-on should only be used if you have valid use case for it (like in these two cases), as the developers introduced these privacy and security enhancing features for a reason.

Comment: that plugin no longer seems available (link in the installation section doesnt work anymore)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this to [UserChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css&printable=yes)

```css
#webrtcIndicator {
  display: none;
}
```

Source: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/78pjz1/how_do_i_remove_this_microphone_indicator/)

Answer (score 1):

`(Settings) Hamburger Menu` -> `Help` -> `TroubleShooting` -> `Profile Folder` -> `Open Folder` -> create folder `chrome` -> inside `chrome` create `userChrome.css` -> contents of `userChrome.css`:

```css
#webrtcIndicator {
  display: none;
}
```

Then `//about:config`
Then flip `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to true

Restart Firefox

No wonder they are losing marketshare with such user-hostile behavior